# Why can't Angular find an controller for a directive on an external file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular, and I'm having a hard time following [John Papa's guidelines](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide). His snippets tell me to put my controller logic inside my directives, but that doesn't make sense to me. I've tried doing it myself, and I can't seem to make it work this way too, but I think that this is not optimal, as I can't have my controller tidily separated on his own file, and I have to make my `.directive.js` just bigger and clunkier. I'm yet to find an example where somebody didn't use the controller-logic-inside-the-directive.

Here's what I'm trying to do...
This is my funcionario-list-all.directive.js:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('i9t.funcionario').directive('i9tFuncionariosListAll',
            funcionariosListAll);

    //directive.$inject = [];

    /* @ngInject */
    function funcionariosListAll() {
        // Usage:
        //
        // Creates:
        //
        var directive = {
            bindToController : true,
            templateUrl : 'funcionario-listall.html',
            controller : FuncionarioController,
            controllerAs : 'funcCtrl',
            restrict : 'AE'
        };
        return directive;
    }

//  angular.module('i9t.funcionario').controller('FuncionarioController',
//          FuncionarioController);
//  FuncionarioController.$inject = [ '$scope', '$http' ];
//
//  /* @ngInject */
//  function FuncionarioController($scope, $http) {
//      // Why do i need to do this...
//      var vm = this;
//      vm.funcionarios = [];
//      // To make this expression execute when the page loads?
//      $http.get("./funcionario/listarFuncionarios").then(function(data) {
//          vm.funcionarios = data.data;
//      });
//      vm.updateFuncionario = updateFuncionario;
//      // //////////////
//
//      function updateFuncionario(funcId) {
//          vm.funcionarios = [ {
//              id : 1,
//              nome : 'papillon',
//              endereco : 'Saint-Martin-de-Ré'
//          }, {
//              id : 2,
//              nome : 'montressor',
//              endereco : 'La Rochelle'
//          } ];
//      }
//  }

})();
```

It can't find my controller, that is defined as `funcionario.controller.js` and has that commented code. It won't work if I can't put the controller logic onto the directive, but I'd like to have it all separated, for when it gets bigger, and then I wouldn't need to alter the directive (too much, at least). They are on the same folder, and I'm declaring the `i9t.funcionario` module on a `funcionario.module.js` on the same folder. Should I be injecting the controller in the directive for it to work? Making a separate module just for the controller? I've tried that, but it didn't work.
I'm using Angular 1.4.4, just learned it from CodeSchool and Thinkster, so I might be making some dumb mistake without realizing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *registering* your controller in a separate file with angular. That file's scope is different and, hence, the variable name `FuncionarioController` is not defined where the directive is being initialized.

Angular allows you to register controllers with the module, as you are doing in `funcionario.controller.js`, and you have given it the name `'FuncionarioController'`. This string name doesn't necessarily have to be the name of the function which implements the controller (which can also be an anonymous function). Hence, you could have named it `'foo'` as well.

Now, to tell angular that you want to access that controller, you can use the *name* you registered it with. This is similar to how you are injecting `$scope` and `$http` into your controller; they are also merely services which were registered with angular.

In your particular example, you can also pass the `name` as the argument `controller` (which in your case is `FuncionarioController`, but could have been `foo` as well). Hence, this should work for you:

```
function funcionariosListAll() {
    // Usage:
    //
    // Creates:
    //
    var directive = {
        bindToController : true,
        templateUrl : 'funcionario-listall.html',
        controller : 'FuncionarioController', // <-- string here
        controllerAs : 'funcCtrl',
        restrict : 'AE'
    };
    return directive;
}
```

Comment: Really thanks! I was thinking on maintaining the previous structure, but i hadn't noticed that i could use the actual name for another things. I thought that since they were on the same module, they could be easily referenced. But, as another thing, say that i wanted to invoke a method on a service. I'd need to inject it through the normal method, right? Or is there a way of invoking some method from said controller using that reference? Thanks again!

Comment: @Yuri-M-Dias The names are **only** used for dependency injection in JS code. You can get to the object they refer to either via dependency injection the standard way, or using `$injector` service, but then you'll have to invoke the methods on the Plain Javascript Objects yourself. You cannot 'hop' over dependency injection and call `'FuncionarioService.get()'`.